# Getting PHP to access a 32-bit COM object in a 64-bit OS

Tags: php, windows, apache, com, dcom

I've recently upgraded my old home server system to a 64-bit system (Win 7) and have a problem in accessing a 32-bit home automation DCOM object in PHP.  I'm running 32-bit Apache, and so far as I'm aware, 32-bit PHP (I don't think there's a 64-bit version available).  The only difference between this setup and my old (but working) setup, is that I'm running the 64-bit Windows 7 rather than 32-bit.

When I reinstalled everything, I was initially puzzled how I couldn't configure access to the DCOM object as dcomcnfg.exe didn't show it.  It was a while before I realised I had to launch the 32-bit version of dcomcnfg.exe in order to see the DCOM object (`mmc comexp.msc /32`).

I'm now trying to access this 32-bit DCOM object in PHP but it just doesn't work.  Considering Apache and PHP is 32-bit, I'm oddly surprised that I can't script in PHP to access this COM object.

Does anyone know how I can access this (very old) 32-bit COM object in PHP?

A code snippet of what I'm trying to do is shown here:

```
    $hs = new COM("HomeSeer.clsString") or die("Unable to get DCOM object");
    $hs->ExecX10("a5","on","0","0");
    unset($hs);
```

I really hope someone can help, otherwise this transition to 64-bit Windows will be a bit of a disaster for me!

I've read in various places how putting files into the c:\windows\syswow64\ folder might be a workaround, but I just have no idea what files to put in there?  Are we saying I should install the home automation software in that folder?  Surely not...!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too.

So far my research suggests that this is not possible. One way this could have been possible is through IIS (enable 32bit DLLS for 64 bit applications) . I tried that but to no avail.

Hopefully someone more knowledgeable about Windows than me knows how to do this.